# How to read/store the contents of a Selenium grid/table?

Tags: perl, selenium

In the UI, i click on button it displays the some details in new window. In this data appears in grid/table format. I'm using Selenium IDE to record & export the testcase in perl. But i'm unable to read/store those grid/table contents. How can i do it ? Can you please let me know ?

Is it possible to do it with the help of IDE commands (like getting the total number of rows & columns) ? I could only retrieve the value of the particular cell. But xpath changes for every cell, so even i can't iterate it too. Any possible ways ?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE doesn't produce very maintainable tests, when I last used it there was an 'export as perl' option - use that instead of trying to convert the grid/table yourself.

If you can I'd suggest looking at using [Test::WWW::Selenium::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium%3a%3aMore) instead, you can write very clean and modular test code like this:

```
use Test::Most;
use Test::WWW::Selenium::More;

my $s = Test::WWW::Selenium::More->new( 
    host           => "localhost", # selenium server host
    port           => 4444,        # selenium server port
    browser        => "*firefox",
    browser_url    => "http://www.google.com",
);

$s->open_ok("http://www.google.com", undef, "fetched G's site alright");
$s->type_ok( "q", "hello world");
$s->click_ok("btnG");
$s->wait_for_page_to_load_ok(5000);
$s->title_like(qr/Google Search/);

done_testing;
```

Have a read of the [Manual](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium%3a%3aMore%3a%3aManual) and [Test::WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium) which this is an extension of (anything you can to in Test::WWW::Selenium you can do in ::More).